# Is there any clean way to avoid hitting the filesystem when copying the contents of an ImageField?

Tags: django, image, orm

I'm on Django 1.4 for the moment. I'm trying to figure out a way to copy an image field from one object to another without hitting the file system to grab the height and width. In case it's relevant, the source and destination objects are of different models. And the reason this is of interest is that I'm using S3 as a storage backend, which is more cumbersome than a simple disk hit.

Usually, if I say:

```python
obj2.image = obj1.image
```

It will grab the file from the FS, figure out the width and height, and save those to the specified width and height fields. However, in principle I think I should be able to say:

```python
obj2.image_width = obj1.image_width
obj2.image_height = obj1.image_height
obj2.image = obj1.image
```

In fact, I imagine that Django itself could do this under the hood without grabbing the file every time. Perhaps it does so in some versions later than 1.4.

I've been playing around with it a lot, and looking at the Django source, and learning a bit about the quirks of when it happens. `update_dimension_fields` is the function in question, and [it's called with `force=True` in `ImageFileDescriptor.__set__`.](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L307)

One way I've figured out how to partially avoid it is:

```python
obj2.image = obj1.image
obj3.image = obj1.image
obj4.image = obj1.image
...
```

Ie, it only hits the file system the first time. But of course it still hits it unnecessarily the first time, and further this doesn't help anything between requests. The other thing I thought of is:

```python
Model.objects.filter(pk=obj2.pk).update(
    image=obj1.image,
    image_width=obj1.image_width,
    image_height=obj2.image_height
)
```

This only works because it's dumbed down as far as ORM safety goes. I'd use it, except I want to do this within a ModelForm. Which means I'd have to override the `save` function:

```python
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = super(MyModelForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    Model.objects.filter(pk=obj.pk).update( # extra query!
        image=source.image,
        image_width=source.image_width,
        image_height=source.image_height
    )
    return Model.objects.get(pk=obj.pk) # another extra query!
```

The problem is the two extra queries, just to get around a framework quirk. The second extra query is so that obj.image is the expected image, for whatever consumes the form. I could skip it if I were 100% sure the form consumer isn't going to need it, which is not a good idea.

So is there a way around this? Is there a good safety concern I'm not thinking of, that explains why I'm *not* able to do this?